# Fetching data from mongo db collection failing to found data

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

I'm using mongo db and angular for an eCommerce application.

Requirement is to get items under each user in cart.

Here while fetching I'm using the objectId as the reference to find the data, Its not finding out any data from the DB.

```js
exports.findAllCartItems = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
   insertTocartItem.find(id)
    .then(data => {
      if (!data)
        res.status(404).send({ message: "Cart Is empty" });
      else res.send([data]);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send({ message: "Error while showing Cart" });
    }); 
};
```

Data In collection:

```js
  "_id": "$oid": "6347caf515a675847127b020"
  "parentcategoryId": 1000,
  "brandName": "Nothing",
  "modelName": "1",
  "Price": "30000",
  "itemsImage": "http://localhost:8080/public/1664539223328--Nothing_phon.jpg",
  "itemsubCatId": "7000",
  "itemId": "7000MB1",
  ***"userInfoId": "634677b7ce60d9d8cd591940",***
  "__v": 0
```

I'm passing userInfoId": "634677b7ce60d9d8cd591940 from frontend, I'm able to see the ID in req.params.id but unable to find the matching  data.

If changed *insertTocartItem.find(id) to insertTocartItem.find({id})* it is fetching entire data in the cart irrespective of userInfoId.

Kindly help with any method to find the data based on userInfoId.

Comment: What is `insertToCartItem`?

Comment: Its just a function trying to add item to db

Comment: Can you add it's definition in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct in the query which field you want to search.

```
exports.findAllCartItems = (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
   insertTocartItem.find({userInfoId: id})
    .then(data => {
      if (!data)
        res.status(404).send({ message: "Cart Is empty" });
      else res.send([data]);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res
        .status(500)
        .send({ message: "Error while showing Cart" });
    }); 
};
```

Comment: getting this error while trying  insertTocartItem.find({userInfoId: id})   TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at exports.findAllCartItems (D:\mean-stack-angular-14-master\node-express-server\app\controllers\cart.controller.js:48:5)

Answer (score 0):

See you have to pass `id` in `_id` property to find the data like this,

```
insertTocartItem.find({_id: id}) // Here, replace '_id' with which field you want to search for, for ex: {userInfoId: id}
```

The thing is mongoose schema is an object based right so in`find()` method you have to pass schema property key that is `_id` and value that is `req.params.id`.

Or If you dont want to pass an object then you can use `findById()` method like this,

```
insertTocartItem.findById(id)
```

Comment: getting this error while trying insertTocartItem.find({userInfoId: id}) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') at exports.findAllCartItems (D:\mean-stack-angular-14-master\node-express-server\app\controllers\cart.controller.js:48:5)

Comment: Iam using mongoose 6.6.1 and working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
insertTocartItem.find({_id: id})
```

You should indicate which field you wanna apply the request to...

Answer (score 0):

After using async/await it's working fine, Thanks for all the suggestions.

```
exports.findAllAdresses =  async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  try {
    let data=  await insertTocartItem.find({userInfoId:id}) 
    if (!data) {
      res.status(404).send({ message: "Item Not found" });
    } else res.send(data);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log(error.message)
  }
}
```